# Why ever use zsh array-parameters?

Tags: zsh

```
list=(1 2 3)
for i in $list; do echo $i; done;
for i in $list[@]; do echo $i; done;
for i in $list[*]; do echo $i; done;
for i in ${list}; do echo $i; done;
for i in ${list[@]}; do echo $i; done;
for i in ${list[*]}; do echo $i; done;
for i in "${list[@]}"; do echo $i; done;
```

All of these print the same thing:

```
1 
2
3
```

These

```
for i in "$list"; do echo $i; done;
for i in "${list}"; do echo $i; done;
for i in "$list[*]"; do echo $i; done;
for i in "${list[*]}"; do echo $i; done;
```

all print

```
1 2 3
```

When should I use brackets vs. no brackets and `@` vs. `*`? For example, I [know the difference between](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters) `"${list[@]}"` and `"${list[*]}"`, but I have not been able to find a straightforward answer on the difference between `$list`, `${list}`, `$list[@]`, `${list[@]}`, `$list[*]`, and `${list[*]}`. Why would I ever use array parameters when I could just do `$list`?

Similarly, why wouldn't I just `"$list"` when I want all of the elements in the array in one string? In that case I have, insanely, **4** different options: `"$list"`, `"${list}"`, `"$list[*]"`, `"${list[*]}"`.

Comment: This only happens in zsh, not bash, so I removed the bash tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, it is up to us to which to use. But it could be worthwhile to dig into why zsh permits to write codes like these.

From zsh FAQ documents:

> 1.2: What is it?
>
> Zsh is a UNIX command interpreter (shell) which of the standard shells most resembles the Korn shell (ksh);
>
> ---  [Chapter 1: Introducing zsh and how to install it, Z-Shell Frequently-Asked Questions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq01.html#l1)

and,

> Chapter 2: How does zsh differ from...?
>
> As has already been mentioned, zsh is most similar to ksh, while many of the additions are to please csh users.
>
> ...
>
> 2.1: Differences from sh and ksh
>
> Most features of ksh (and hence also of sh) are implemented in zsh; problems can arise because the implementation is slightly different.
>
> ---  [Chapter 2: How does zsh differ from...?, Z-Shell Frequently-Asked Questions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#l9)

I tell myself it should be noted that zsh has lots of ksh like features and emulation options when I write my own zsh scripts. You could experiment with [`setopt ksh_arrays`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSH_005fARRAYS) to see what is going on, too.

> Arrays are (by default) more csh-like than ksh-like: subscripts start at 1, not 0; `array[0]` refers to `array[1]`; `$array` refers to the whole array, not `$array[0]`; braces are unnecessary: `$a[1]` == `${a[1]}`, etc. Set the [`KSH_ARRAYS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSH_005fARRAYS) option for compatibility.
>
> ---  [2.1: Differences from sh and ksh, Z-Shell Frequently-Asked Questions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#21)

It could give some hints/answers by showing some comparisons with ksh.

## brackets vs. no brackets

> Q22. Why are the braces required with array references, e. g. `${x[1]}`?
>
> A22. It would be nice to do `$x[1]`, but the POSIX shell would expand `$x` and then search for the file pattern resulting by concatenating `[1]`. ksh is POSIX compatible.
>
> ---  [III SHELL PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS Q22, KSH-93 - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.kornshell.com/doc/faq.html)

ksh treats array parameters like this:

```
list=(a b c)
echo $list[1]
;# => "a[1]"
;# concatination of the first $list element and "[1]" string
;# rather than below!
echo ${list[1]} ;# => "b"
```

So, it could be used any of `$list`, `${list}`, `$list[@]`, `${list[@]}`, `$list[*]`, and `${list[*]}` in the first example; it could be considered as feature of zsh.

You could look at the codes from another angle by reading above ksh document's `$x[1]` to `$list[@]` or `$list[*]`.

Note: In zsh, if `$list` contains empty value(s), `"${list[@]}"` differs according to "[24. Empty argument removal](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules)".

> 24. Empty argument removal
>
> If the substitution does not appear in double quotes, any resulting zero-length argument, whether from a scalar or an element of an array, is elided from the list of arguments inserted into the command line.
>
> ---  [24. Empty argument removal, Rules, Expansion, zshparam(1)](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules)

## `@` vs. `*`

> Q1. What is the difference between `*` and `@`, for example, and ?
>
> A1. When used outside of `""`, they are equivalent. However, within double quotes, `"$@"` produces one argument for each positional parameter, and `"$*"` produces a single argument. Note that `"$@"` preserves arguments lists, whereas `$*` may not unless both word splitting and pathname expansion are disabled.
>
> ---  [III SHELL PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS Q1, KSH-93 - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.kornshell.com/doc/faq.html)

This first half is same as zsh as you know. Here is a same reference for zsh document you suggested:

> A subscript of the form `[*]` or `[@]` evaluates to all elements of an array; there is no difference between the two except when they appear within double quotes.
>
> `"$foo[*]"` evaluates to `"$foo[1] $foo[2] ..."`, whereas `"$foo[@]"` evaluates to `"$foo[1]" "$foo[2]" ...`.
>
> ...
>
> When an array parameter is referenced as `$name` (with no subscript) it evaluates to `$name[*]`,
>
> ---  [Array Subscripts, zshparam(1)](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts)

## `"$list"` vs. others

As you can see it would be already clear, zsh gives us 4 different options as its feature. But I think that ksh user could say that:

`"$list"`, `"${list}"` and `"$list[*]"` could mean that it would be doing just some operation on the first element of `$list` (and the result of concatinating `"[*]"` for the latter) rather than list/array references.

---

Here is an example code:

```
list=(1 2 '' 3) # XXX: added an empty entry to check the difference

test-list-dq () {
  echo "$1"
  local i=
  echo '$list:';        for i in $list; do echo $i; done;
  echo '$list[@]:';     for i in $list[@]; do echo $i; done;
  echo '$list[*]:';     for i in $list[*]; do echo $i; done;
  echo '${list}:';      for i in ${list}; do echo $i; done;
  echo '${list[@]}:';   for i in ${list[@]}; do echo $i; done;
  echo '${list[*]}:';   for i in ${list[*]}; do echo $i; done;
  echo '"${list[@]}":'; for i in "${list[@]}"; do echo $i; done;
}

test-list-nq () {
  echo "$1"
  local i=
  for i in "$list"; do echo $i; done
  for i in "${list}"; do echo $i; done
  for i in "$list[*]"; do echo $i; done
  for i in "${list[*]}"; do echo $i; done
}

echo "*double quotes"
test-list-dq "*default"
()  {
  setopt localoptions ksharrays no_nomatch
  test-list-dq "*ksharrays on"
}

echo "*no quotes"
test-list-nq "*default"
()  {
  setopt localoptions ksharrays no_nomatch
  test-list-nq "*ksharrays on"
}
```

Outputs below:

```
*double quotes
*default
$list:
1
2
3
$list[@]:
1
2
3
$list[*]:
1
2
3
${list}:
1
2
3
${list[@]}:
1
2
3
${list[*]}:
1
2
3
"${list[@]}":
1
2

3
*ksharrays on
$list:
1
$list[@]:
1[@]
$list[*]:
1[*]
${list}:
1
${list[@]}:
1
2
3
${list[*]}:
1
2
3
"${list[@]}":
1
2

3
*no quotes
*default
1 2  3
1 2  3
1 2  3
1 2  3
*ksharrays on
1
1
1[*]
1 2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the same with

```
list=('a b' $'c\nd')
```

Also, set `$IFS` to e.g. `'|'` to see how `${list[*]}` works.

```
list=('a b' $'c\nd')
IFS='|'
printf %s "${list[*]}"
```