# Arguments in array with quotes in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have an array with some arguments and want to pass them to a command in zsh, but I get the error that "Quotes must be used around service names which contain spaces".

I have an my_array that is created from a list output of a command, like:
thing one
thing two
thing three
So the my_array should be ("thing one" "thing two" "thing three").

Now I want to do: command_thing $my_array, but apparently the quotes are not passed to the command.

My script looks something like:

```
my_array=($(create list from command))
command_thing $my_array
```

What is the best and quickest way to fix this?

Comment: `${my_array[@]}`?

Comment: Various array expansion methods are covered in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414816/11082165

Comment: The error comes from the command, not from zsh. You need to specify at least, how the arguments are supposed to look like for this command. From a zsh view point, you did everything correctly; the shell is not removing any quotes in the code you posted. Of course there could also be an error in the way you populate the array from the `create list` command, but here too, you don't provide any information, so we can not diagnose anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an my_array that is created from a list output of a command, like: thing one thing two thing three So the my_array should be ("thing one" "thing two" "thing three").

Than the command should output the list like: "thing one" "thing two" "thing three". You cannot expect Zsh to magically add double quotes which are not in the input.

If that's not an option you can work with the following command substitution:

```
x=('thing one' 'thing two' 'thing three')

echo "${x[@]}"
# outputs: thing one thing two thing three

echo "$(printf '"%s" ' "${x[@]}")"
# outputs: "thing one" "thing two" "thing three" 
# note that it has a trailing space after the last quote
```

so `command_thing "$(printf '"%s" ' "${my_array[@]}"` would probably work for you. But note that this passes the values surrounded by quotes as one argument to command_thing. For most correctly working commands that would make things worse.

If you can you should better improve "command_thing". It gets called with three separate arguments and it fails to handle them correctly if they contain spaces. The extra quotes around shouldn't be necessary.

---

If it would be required to pass the array elements as separate arguments to command_thing but still surrounded with quotes you could just preprocess the values like this

```
x=('thing one' 'thing two' 'thing three')
xq=()
for v in "${x[@]}"; do
  # add value v surrounded with double quotes to array xq
  xq+=("\"$v\"")
done
command_thing "${xq[@]}"
```

Comment: The quotes and the @ index are unnecessary in zsh. You can just write `command_thing $xq`. But you are right that your approach would add double quotes to all array elements. I just wonder what weird `command_thing` is invoked here, that it would request double quotes around every argument. I feel that the question posted here is simply too unclear to be answered in an useful way.